# Device app list is empty in Xcode and iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I can't see the apps installed on my device in the Xcode's "Devices" window nor in iTunes (although iTunes says 6 apps installed, no clickable icon appears in the list).

iOS 9.0,
Xcode 7.0,
iTunes 12.3,
Mac OS X 10.10.4

I am trying to get hold of the device log files (not crash files), so if there is another solution for that I also take it.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: try to open in previous Xcode version.

Comment: @MihirOza Did not work, thanks anyway.